# Is it Possible To hide an information in a Image and convert it to video and decrypt it back with FFMPEG

Tags: c#-4.0, ffmpeg

I am doing my project with the help of ffmpeg. I initially convert a video file in to images and hide some information in one of the images and convert it back to video. and in the receiver side the user should again convert the video containing the encrypted message in to images and get back the information from the image in which we have previously hided the information.

I have done all these but after convert the encrypted image into video and then i convert back to image i am not able to get the hidden information from the converted image...How do i do this. Is there any way to hide infor mation in a image other than this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never done that before but I wouldn't see why this is not possible if you use lossless compression.

Example of command to convert from image sequence to video:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i images%03d.png -r 25 -c:v png testImg2.avi -y
```

Example of command to convert video back to image sequence:

```
ffmpeg -i testImg2.avi -f image2 imagesNew%03d.png -y
```

These 2 commands give me the exact same png files before / after: MD5 hashes are identical.

Comment: Its not working. I have 256 sequence of images and i have converted it to video... when i convert the video back i am not getting the same image set.... which has one extra image... i dont get the actual image which i have converted....

Comment: As I said this is working for me, I tested it on a sequence of 75 frames. I can't even guess why you're getting an extra frame, somebody else's input might help. Btw, is your initial sequence made of PNG files?

Comment: Thanks AJ29.If i have hided the information in the first frame then i  convert it back to video. and when i convert the video back to image i have got the information from the next frame (i.e if i have hided my information in first frame then i get it back from the second frame). your code helped me in some way... thanks......